# Join XML fragments in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

i have this code

```
select * from #ENTETE
for xml path ('ENTETE')

select * from #DECLARATION
for xml path ('DECLARATION')


select * from #CARACTERISTIQUE_TITRE
for xml path ('CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE') 

select * from #MOUVEMENT_TITRE
for xml path ('MOUVEMENT_TITRE') 


select * from #ENCOURS
for xml path ('ENCOURS')
```

and i have this result

[image]

but i want to have this result

RESULT that i wish

[image]

Comment: This example shows only one record per table. Edit the question add more data & expected result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select '20190302' as date_declaration, 'abc' as Type_Fischier, 1 AS numero_de_remise
into #ENTETE;

select '' as cib_emetteur into #DECLARATION;

select 'c' as type_mouvement, 11111 as type_tcn, 'fr12345' as code_isin
into #CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE;
go

select
(
select *
from #ENTETE
for xml path('ENTETE'), type
), 
(
select *
from #DECLARATION
for xml path('DECLARATION'), type
),
(
select *
from #CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE
for xml path('CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE'), type
)
for xml path(''), type;

declare @result xml = (
select
(
select *
from #ENTETE
for xml path('ENTETE'), type
), 
(
select *
from #DECLARATION
for xml path('DECLARATION'), type
),
(
select *
from #CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE
for xml path('CARATERISTIQUE_TITRE'), type
)
for xml path(''), type
);

select @result;
go
```